# How to debug "Could not add identity : agent refused operation" on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script on `Gitlab CI` using Windows that will imitate my Linux build. As a first step, I need to add a private key so that I can download all of required submodules:

```bsh
mkdir C:\Users\$env:UserName\.ssh
$key_path = "C:\Users\$env:UserName\.ssh\id_rsa"
echo "$DEPLOY_PRIVATE_KEY" > $key_path
(Get-Content $key_path -Raw).Replace("`r`n","`n") | Set-Content $key_path -Force
Set-Service -Name ssh-agent -StartupType Manual
Start-Service ssh-agent
ssh-add
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Could not add identity "C:\Users\gitlab_runner/.ssh/id_rsa": agent refused operation
```

and because I don't really know Windows, I am not sure how to approch this. Unfortunately, Windows mirror of `ssh-add` does not have verbose mode `-v`. How can I get more info about agent refusal? What could be the reason for the refusal?

Cheers!

**EDIT**

Following @VonC suggestion, I made sure permissions of the folder/key are not too open and that my agent is indeed running:

```sh
$ Cmd /c Icacls  %UserProfile%\.ssh /c /t /Inheritance:d
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh\id_rsa
 Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files
$ Cmd /c Icacls  %UserProfile%\.ssh /c /t /Grant %UserName%:F
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh\id_rsa
 Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files
$ Cmd /c Icacls  %UserProfile%\.ssh /c /t /Remove Administrator "Authenticated Users" BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN Everyone System Users
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh
 processed file: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\.ssh\id_rsa
 Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

```sh
$ Get-Service ssh-agent
 Status   Name               DisplayName                           
 ------   ----               -----------                           
 Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agen
```

From a code perspective, I looked into `ssh-add.c` of openssh repo and , if I'm not wrong, found that error `SSH_ERR_AGENT_FAILURE`  is thrown on fetching identity list.

Comment: Do you want the linux version? Does `bash -c "ssh-add -v"` work?

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, make sure to the permissions of the `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` you just created are not too opened: see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1329702/141) to fix it.

Check the state of the SSH-Agent service to confirm it was indeed started, as in [this issue](https://github.com/rupor-github/ssh-agent-wsl/issues/3#issuecomment-415253514).

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting some errors on the permission change. Once I will figure it out , I will get back to you :) Have a nice day :))

Comment: So I followed both suggestions and unfortunately I didn't manage to add the key. For the record, I got information from `Icacls` that for every command, processing of the key (and folder) was successful and `Get-Service ssh-agent` returned running. Would it be ok to update my post with steps I performed?

Comment: @Proko Sure: edit your question to add more details.