# Why does ssh-add fail on MobaXterm: is it a permissions issue?

Tags: ssh, private-key, mobaxterm

I'm attempting to link my Windows 11 PC to my Github account using ssh (as per [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)). I'm using cygwin in MobaXterm, and have successfully completed the process previously on a Windows 7 machine. The problem this time arises when trying to add the private-key using ssh-add; it produces the error
`Could not add identity "/home/mobaxterm/.ssh/id_ed25519": agent refused operation`. I definitely have the agent running.

[Previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247463/how-to-debug-could-not-add-identity-agent-refused-operation-on-windows) have identified overly lax file permissions as a cause for this error. I have set the persistent home directory to a folder on my C drive, and in that directory given .ssh permissions 700 and the id_ed25519 file permissions 600 (and checked that they have been applied). However, `ls -la /home/mobaxterm/.ssh` reveals id_ed25519 has permissions 644. I don't understand how the permissions can be different, as I assumed /home/mobaxterm is just a symbolic link: if I delete or add files in my directory, the changes are reflected in /home/mobaxterm. Running chmod directly on /home/mobaxterm has no effect.

I would be very grateful for help, as at present I can't push files to my GitHub!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to SSH with private keys using MobaXterm:

1. Local terminal
2. SSH session

**Pre-requisite**

For both of the options you'll need to add your private keys in PPK format to PageAnt (installed with Putty) and specify you `Use external Pageant` in MobaXterm SSH settings:
[image]
Refer to step 1 of [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pageant-to-streamline-ssh-key-authentication-with-putty) to learn how to add keys to PageAnt.

Note that PageAnt only accepts keys in PPK format, so you may need to convert your key pair to such format. You can do so with PuttyGen (refer to SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190667/convert-pem-to-ppk-file-format/3190723#3190723))

**Option 1 - Local terminal**

- Start a local terminal and notice your current folder is `/home/mobaxterm`.
- Create a symbolic link to .ssh directory in your Windows profile folder:

  `ln -s /drives/c/Users/<YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME>/.ssh .ssh`
- Run `ssh` including the path to your private key:

  `ssh -i ~/.ssh/<MY_PRIVATE_KEY> <REMOTE_USERNAME>@<REMOTE_SERVER>`

**Option 2 - SSH session**

Create a new SSH session and configure the necessary parameters. Specifically, you must check `Use private key` and point to the **PPK** file:
[image: Private key session settings]

**Additional hints: SSH config**

Regarding operations against GitHub, you can include an entry in `.ssh/config` like:

```
# GitHub for <USERNAME> account
Host github.com
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<PPK_PRIVATE_KEY>
```

This way you could run your git commands and the appropriate key would be automatically picked.

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed that your goal is to use git commands so **Option 2** won't serve your purpose.
I'll leave it, anyway, just in case it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

To have the same config on linux and windows, I do this:

- Use the internal ssh agent provides by Mobaxterm

[image]

- Load the private file:

```
ssh-add /drives/c/foo/<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>
```

After that I'm able to clone my git repositories using ssh